# JSP button click issue

Tags: jsp, button

I am writing a basic jsp program where upon clicking the Add user button should display a form on the same page to be filled. but the click is not being recognized. I debugged the code but it seems it is not reading the "addUsers" button. The value i always receive with request.getParameter is null.

```
    <%

        if (request.getParameter("addUser")!=null){
            out.println("<button type=\"Submit\" name=\"deletehData\">Delete Data</button>");
            out.println("<table>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td><b>First Name:</b></td>");
            out.println("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"firstName\" > </td>");
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            out.println("</tr><tr><td><b>Last Name:</b></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"lastName\" ></td>");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName"); 
            out.println("</tr><tr><td><b>Email ID:</b></td>");
            out.println("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"emailID\" > </td>");
            String emailID = request.getParameter("emailID");
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td><b>Phone Number (M):</b></td>");
            out.println("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"phoneNo\"> </td>");
            String mobileno = request.getParameter("phoneNo");
            out.println("</tr></table>");
        }
%>
```

Here is the button code.

```
<table>
    <tr> <td><button type="Submit" name="addUsers" >Add User</button></td></tr>
    <tr> <td><button type="Submit" name="readData">Read Data</button><br></td></tr>
    <tr> <td><button type="Submit" name="updateData">Update Data</button></td></tr>
    <tr> <td><button type="Submit" name="deleteData">Delete Data</button></td></tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: request.getParameter("addUser")!=null has been changed to request.getParameter("addUsers")!=null, still not working.

Comment: Bcs you have to send your code with FORM! Then next page you can values with request.getParameter("");

Answer (score 0):

clicking on button does not do anything.
You need to define a JavaScript function and register using

```
<button type="Submit" name="addUsers" onclick="doSomething()">Add User</button>
```

implement the doSomething() function to make ajax request with parameters.